# PHP/MySQLi Not finding existing user

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

For some reason, the code seems to not be able to find any existing usernames. I can't find anything wrong with my code though. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    $Name = $_POST["User"];
        $Pass = $_POST["Pass"];
        $get = "SELECT * FROM Logins";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $get);
        $found = false;

        echo $Name;         

        $sql=mysqli_query("SELECT FROM Logins (ID, Username, Password) WHERE Username=$Name");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
            echo "Username Taken";
        } else {
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Logins (ID, Username, Password) VALUES (0, '$Name', '$Pass')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                echo "Account Created";
            } else {
                echo mysqli_error($conn);
            }
        }
```

When I post to the site, $Name is correct.

Comment: You're missing quotes around your string value in your query. mysqli_error() would tell you that if you used it to check for errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect syntax near your select statement. It's

```
SELECT FROM Logins (ID, Username, Password) WHERE Username=$Name")
```

You need:

```
SELECT ID, Username, Password 
FROM Logins 
WHERE Username='$Name'
```

Also note, you should be using prepared statement which will avoid need for quotes and will avoid your code vulnerable from SQL Injection.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any difference using either way.

Comment: what's the issue now?

Comment: It's exactly the same. For some reason, even if a user doesn't exist, it inserts the user info into the database too.